# Which authentication to user between a IoT device and the APIs?

Tags: api, authentication

I am building this IoT device which should send data to an API.
I would use some "hardcoded" api key to access it, but on the other side I also have a front-end that uses JWT to access data.

What do you suggest? Maybe RPC instead?

Comment: How worried are you about people disassembling your device and then sending spurious data to the API?

Comment: Not at all for now, it's just me using it and I can hardly see anybody else doing it :D

Comment: You might be interestes in [OWASP : IoT Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Internet_of_Things_Project])

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using OAuth2 with JWT you can use the `urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer` client assertion type as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-2.2

in a nutshell, each device has it's own private/public key pair, private keys are on stored on the devices and public keys are stored in your authentication server. when a device needs to obtain an access token it creates a JWT with set of claims (e.g. device id) and signs it with it's private key. this JWT is sent to the authentication server as jwt-bearer in the `urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer` request. The authentication server validates the signature, know which device it is from the JWT and responds back with an access token.

Comment: Is there a possibility that someone takes apart the device-side code and finds the private key?  If not, how is that data secured?

Comment: private key generation should be done some private server and send to device, and once it's job done, key shall be destroyed.